# In Assembly, Do Instructions Specify Data Types?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm a beginner in Assembly language programming (x86).

Is the following true for it?

In Assembly data types like BYTE, WORD, DWORD mean 8bit,16bit and 32 bit patterns respectively, not only INTEGERS. They don't have a meaning by themselves, they are just bit patterns. Instructions which use them are what give them a meaning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Assembly" code is about many special instructions that operate on various size operands (for x86, 1 or more bytes) that contain values that the individual instructions *assume* are of a *particular* type.

Most of the basic instruction set (e.g.,  ADD, CMP, XOR) assumes/treats its operands as if they were N-byte 2's complement integers.  BYTE, DWORD, etc. are hints for saying what "N" is.

Note: 2's complement is used by most modern computers, because ADD, SUBTRACT and CMP (because it is essentially a subtract) produce the right answer whether you interpret the operands as signed with signed result, or unsigned with unsigned result, so you only need one ADD and one SUB instruction instead of one for each type.  [After a CMP, you do need to know whether the operands were signed or unsigned. Most modern CPUs simply produce unsigned-cmp and signed-cmp results from the CMP instruction, so you only need one CMP instruction.  The compare status is stored usually in a CC which has bits for both unsigned and signed comp results.  You do need  JMP SIGNED LESS and JUMP UNSIGNED LESS instructions].

The so-called "floating point" instructions generally treat their operands as if they were 32 bit or 64 bit IEEE floating point numbers.  There are some "crossover" instructions that treat one operand as a 2's complement integer; this allow programs to convert between these representations.

The so-called string instructions treat the operand as a register ECX long string of 1,2,4 or 8 byte values.

The various vector instructions treat their operands as short vectors of  2's complement integers, or as floating point numbers.

So, yes, each individual machine instruction *assumes* specific data types for its operands.

The x86 assembly source code often confuses people on this point, because it is appears that the assembly language programmer is specifying a explicit type, e.g.  DWORD,   or QWORD PTR.  What is really going on is that the coder is writing the name of a broad class of instructions (e.g., MOV), and providing enough hints so that the assembler can choose the specific binary machine instruction that *assumes* the explicitly coded data type.

Comment: Worth pointing out that addition / subtraction are the same binary operation for unsigned and for 2's complement, which is why there aren't separate instructions, and why you just look at unsigned flags (`ja` / `jb`) or signed flags (`jg` / `jl`)  depending on how your program should interpret the data.  [This guide](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt) is good for carry vs. overflow / unsigned vs. signed flags.

Comment: This question is tagged x86; you don't need to be too generic; But I guess you're talking about how x86 fits in with other ISAs.  And BTW, even the low half of `imul` is the same thing for signed/unsigned (hence the lack of 2 or 3 operand or `mul`, just `imul r32,r32`), and of course bitwise stuff doesn't care about the meaning of the bits.