# pushing function to a stack in assembly

Tags: assembly, data-structures, x86-16

After looking up this question

> 1. Replace the following valid instruction with a single instruction that has the same effect. Don’t consider the effect on flags.
>
>    ```
>     push word L1
>     jmp L2
>    L1:
>    ```

I want to know what data types can we `push` or `pop` in assembly and in other HLLs. Also I would be happy to know the answer of the question that I quoted.

Comment: `call L2` would be an instruction that does the same thing I assume this is 16-bit code since the label L1's address is being treated as a WORD. Call is the same thing as pushing the address of the instruction after the call and then jumps to the function. You can only push values on the stack. At a higher level those values may be representative of data types.

Comment: You can push any 16-bit or 32-bit value onto the stack, from a register, immediate, or memory.  If that value is an address, it can be any kind of address, including the address of a label in front of an instruction.  Assembly doesn't have types, just copying bytes around; it's up to the programmer to implement high-level concepts like functions.  (Normally by having `call` push a return address for use with `ret`, but you can do it manually.)

Comment: Related: [Can we say that an x86 CPU has data types?](//stackoverflow.com/q/54573972) / [How many data types are there in Assembly language?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5287710) / [In Assembly, Do Instructions Specify Data Types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27166810). But those are mostly about int vs. float vs. pointer, mostly not talking about code addresses and return values, since those aren't even visible in HLLs.  Also [What happens exactly under the hood to Assembly `push`, `pop`, `call`, and `ret` operations?](//stackoverflow.com/q/59096539) about how call/ret are just push+jmp and pop eip

Comment: Also related: [x64 assembly functions (call/return vs push/pop/jump)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29687203) and [Differences between call, push+ret and push+jump in assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30916768)

Comment: [Using CALL, RET in assembly x86](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36568642) shows what happens when the function you call tries to return with the stack pointing somewhere other than the return address.  It's just bytes, no magic happens, it's up to you to pop the right 2 bytes back into IP with a `ret`, or manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can only push/pop pairs of bytes. If you have a byte in `AL` you want to preserve on the stack, you can't write `push al`, you have to do `push ax`. This isn't a problem, however, as it still accomplishes the task of preserving `AL`.

On a 16-bit x86 CPU, pushing a 32-bit value can be done by pushing a pair of registers. Which register represents the upper 16 bits and which one represents the lower 16 bits is up to you. If you're using a `.386` or newer CPU you can push an entire 32-bit register with a single instruction, e.g. `push eax`.

And to answer the other question, the instruction you're looking for is `call L2`. The `call` function effectively pushes the address of the instruction after it, and then does a `JMP` to the destination of the `call`. The `ret` instruction is effectively `pop ip`, as it takes the top two bytes of the stack and sets the `ip` register two them. (There are "far returns" that work differently, but this is a simplified explanation.)